# Appmaker default Roles

Tags: permissions, google-app-maker

If you allow organization wide access to your application, how do you default users to a specific role in your app?

i'm following an example from a tutorial, and it works great if I specify individual users to have specific roles, but I need to be able to leave this open to the broader org but I only want them using the "user" level.

Comment: You might want to take a look at using Google Groups for this and changing members of the group as needed, then setting roles to the group email in your deployments.

Comment: Here is some documentation on this https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app#add_members_to_roles.

Comment: Great, do you want to put those comments as an answer so I can mark it solved? Groups will be the right way to go I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Google Groups for roles that may involve many individuals where it would become cumbersome to update members in the App Maker deployment settings. There is some information here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app#add_members_to_roles.

If this is strictly an access restriction to the application itself to a subset of individuals within a domain then groups can still be used to restrict access to the application within the application settings.